# Microsoft OpenIdConnect does not prompt for login after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I wired up a test ASP.NET MVC app with .NET 6 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

It's logging in and out of auth0 oidc successfully, but it is not prompting the user for login after it has been logged out

After initial login prompt, when I hit logout, I am seeing redirect happening, and the user is logged out, but when I hit login again, it's refreshing the session without login prompt

I think the problem I am having has to do with the cookies. I tried deleting the cookies in with OnSigningOut event, but it's still not working

```
// auth config in Program.cs, the rest is the sample mvc app code
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Bearer";
})
    .AddCookie("Cookies", ck =>
    {
        ck.Events.OnSigningOut = ctx =>
        {
            foreach (var cookie in ctx.Request.Cookies)
            {
                // this is hit when I logout
                ctx.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("Bearer", oidc =>
    {
        oidc.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        oidc.ClientId = "***********";
        oidc.ClientSecret = "*********************************";
        oidc.MetadataAddress = "https://***.us.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        oidc.ResponseType = "code";

        oidc.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "/";
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
    });

...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

My AccountController, where I handle login and logout

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/")
    {
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties();

        props.RedirectUri = returnUrl;
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Bearer", props);
    }

    public async Task Logout()
    {
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("Index", "Home") };

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Bearer", props).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies").ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of the cookies so the user gets a login prompt after signout?

**Update**

If I hit my oidcs *ping_end_session_endpoint* on the same browser, it will prompt me for login agian. But setting openidconnect to the endpoint still doesn't work

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "https://...";
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```